# Using a triple integral to find volume of a hemisphere radius 1

Tags: integration, spherical-coordinates

My question asks me to use a triple integral to prove that the volume of a hemisphere with radius 1 is
$V=\frac{2}{3}\pi r^3$

I guess I should be using spherical coordinates but I am struggling to know where to start.

thanks universe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The volume element in spherical coordinates is $dV=r^2\sin \theta dr d\theta d \varphi$ And, for a hemisphere of radius $r=1$ the limits of integration are:

$$0<r \le 1 \qquad 0< \theta \le \frac{\pi}{2} \qquad 0<\varphi \le 2\pi
$$

So we can calculate the volume with the triple integral:
$$\int_V dV=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^1 r^2\sin \theta dr d\theta d\varphi
$$

can you do from this?

Comment: Ok. If I evaluate the integral provided I get $ \frac{2\pi}{3}$

Where does the '$r^3$ in

$ \frac{2\pi}{3}r^3$ come from for the formula then?

Comment: $r^3$ comes from if the radius of the sphere is not $R=1$, so  the integral in $r$ goes from $0$ to $R$. ( It is better not use the same symbol $r$ in the integral and in the limit of integration).

Comment: Ahhh. of course. I see now. If I increase the radius to 2 it brings the $r^3$ into play. You are awesome.